# Consequence Operation On Propositional Logical Formulas

Tags: logic

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be independent sets of propositional logical formulas. Can we say that "if $Cn(\Sigma_1)\cap Cn(\Sigma_2)=Cn(\emptyset)$ then $\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2$ is independent?"

P.S.:$Cn$ is consequence operation on propositinal logical formulas.

Comment: Just to make sure: a set $\Sigma$ is independent iff there's no $\Gamma \subset \Sigma$ such that $\Sigma \subset Cn(\Gamma)$?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is an independent set iff for all $\varphi \in \Sigma$, $\Sigma-\{\varphi\}\nvdash \varphi$

Comment: So, rephrasing in terms of $Cn$, this means that, for all $\phi \in \Sigma$, $\phi \not \in Cn(\Sigma \setminus \{\phi\})$?

Comment: Further, is there any property of $Cn$ with respect to union? Something like $Cn(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2) = Cn(\Sigma_1) \cup Cn (\Sigma_2)$? (I doubt this is true, but if there is a similar property, perhaps just an inclusion, that would help).

Comment: That's the property:$Cn(\Sigma_1) \cup Cn(\Sigma_2) \subseteq Cn(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2).$

Comment: Hmm, I *think* the answer is yes, but I'm not sure about how to prove it. The basic idea is that, if $\phi \in Cn(\Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2 \setminus \{\phi\})$, then there must be a $\Gamma \subseteq \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2 \setminus \{\phi\}$ such that $\phi \in Cn(\Gamma)$. $\Gamma$ must have formulas from both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, otherwise it would violate the independence of either set. But if you analyze the possible cases for $\phi$, it seems that every case violates the separateness of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. I can't see a direct argument for it, though...